iptables nat does not capture ICMPv6 packets?
Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to route ICMPv6 packets to another destination and iptables seemed a perfect fit.
So I tried -j DNAT target of the -t nat table and figured out that it essentially had no effect on ICMPv6. By contrast, the default filter table captures the ICMPv6 packets successfully. Indeed, if I add up a LOG target as follows:
# successfully logs incoming ICMPv6 packets
sudo ip6tables -i eth0 -p icmpv6 -d xxxx::xxxx -A INPUT -j LOG

I can see the entries being logged via dmesg. But attaching to the INPUT/PREROUTING chaing of the nat table produces no log entries:
# No logs produced
sudo ip6tables -i eth0 -p icmpv6 -d xxxx::xxxx -A PREROUTING -j LOG -t nat
sudo ip6tables -i eth0 -p icmpv6 -d xxxx::xxxx -A INPUT -j LOG -t nat

This is reasonable since man iptables(8) says

nat:
    This table is consulted when a packet that creates a new connection is  encountered.


and there's no any packets creating new connection related to ICMPv6. The problem is -j DNAT can only be used with -t nat.
Is there a way to route ICMPv6 packets to another destination?


and there's no any packets creating new connection related to ICMPv6. The problem is -j DNAT can only be used with -t nat.

As far as routable ICMPv6 packets go:
Specifically for ICMP "Echo" and "Echo Reply" (i.e. ping packets), it works the same way with ICMP as it does with UDP – the first packet not yet known to conntrack (the iptables connection tracking subsystem) is what creates the flow state, and all subsequent packets are automatically recognized as being part of that flow.
The flow is automatically forgotten (i.e. "connection closed" in manual page terms) after it has been idle for sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp{,v6}_timeout seconds – or after you manually remove it using conntrack -D -p icmpv6.
The main difference from UDP is that instead of src/dst ports, the conntrack entry is keyed by ICMP Echo Request ID (or maybe just by the IP addresses alone). The rarely-used ICMP Timestamp Request would work the same way.
All other ICMP packets that are not requests cannot be DNATed (or rather it makes zero sense to DNAT them separately) because they already belong to an existing flow. For example, an ICMP "Network Unreachable" packet generated in response to a TCP packet will be considered part of the TCP flow (and DNATed/SNATed if and only if the original TCP connection was DNATed/SNATed).
Finally, the ICMPv6-specific "neighbor discovery" packets (NS/NA/RS/RA) cannot be NATed because they are inherently link-local and not forwarded through a router in the first place.

Like Private Experimentation errors with codes 100, 101 that I actually planned to re-route cannot probably be re-routed as well.
